# Is it possible get data with search data between values

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having data in table USER_TABLE as following :

```
+-----------------+
| USERS_RANGE     |
+-----------------+
| 5-98            |
| 9854-98666620   |
| 54-986          |
| 1-20            |
| 10000-122222220 |
| 10-1222         |
+-----------------+
```

My requirement hear:

Ex:- if i search "7" it should display as :

```
+-------------+
| USERS_RANGE |
+-------------+
| 5-98        |
| 1-20        |
+-------------+
```

I tried
ex:- `select * from USER_TABLE WHERE USERS_RANGE <= '7';`
and some more mathamatical things in java
Is there any query to get data like this.

Comment: Hi Madhu, What's the logic, and what have you done so far in order to solve the problem. Kindly you can edit the question to show your current effort.

Comment: I do no know MySQL string-functions, but idea is: split your USER_RANGE-column into two: USER_RANGE_START and USER_RANGE_END (e.g for the first row 5 and 98) and then use BETWEEN

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan i edit question i used <= operator but no use
I don't know is there any possibility to get such data or not.

Comment: what you mean by `if I search "7" it should display as`. What is the logic for this ?

Comment: @Roshan i metion a below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can get the required data using subquery approach and `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` function.

```
/* select all inside subquery and filter with WHERE*/
SELECT USERS_RANGE FROM (
    /* select all range and split the range between '-' */
    SELECT
        USERS_RANGE
        , SUBSTRING_INDEX(USERS_RANGE, '-', 1) AS `from`
        , SUBSTRING_INDEX(USERS_RANGE, '-', -1) AS `to` 
    FROM USERS_RANGE_TABLE
) A
WHERE A.from <= 7 AND A.to >= 7;
```

- The subquery will select all USER_RANGE data, split the range and create a new column with alias `from` and `to`,
- and the main query will select all inside subquery and filter the result with where by column `from` and `to`.

Hope this help answer your question.

Reference:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/subqueries.html